# Adjusting heaps efficiently

Tags: c++, mergesort, heap

**Introduction and context**

I am working on a small application which involves sorting 20GB files as one of the operations. This is being done, due to memory constraints, by breaking them into ~1GB chunks, sorting in memory and then writing back to disk. Then, as stage 2, reading the head of each file and picking the smallest/largest and streaming to the final output file.

This falls into the domain of [External sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

This CR will focus on just one small part of that which involves "picking which chunk to take the next element from" when streaming to the final file. It turns out that this part, and specifically the element comparison, is CPU bound and the bottleneck. The elements being sorted are `std::array<std::byte, 20>`, so a non-trivial comparison, which compiles down to `memcmp`.

**EDIT**
It turns out that we can be significantly faster than `memcmp` with some very simple "big 64-bits load, byte-swap and compares".

See my self answer below
**END-EDIT**

So we need a data structure which makes it easy to pick the next element. Typically there  are around 20 chunks, so my first attempt was just using `std::min_element` because linear search can be really fast for a small number of elements. When I discovered the comparisons were the CPU bottleneck I moved to using a `std::priority_queue`. This reduced the comparisons by > 2x, so that was a big gain.

For clarification, that reduction in the number of comparisons, also brought a 2x speed up in the full application, from 6mins for the merge stage of the 20 x 1GB files, down to 3mins. But at 3mins, the CPU is still @ 100% and almost all inside the `operator<` of the 20 byte array.

This CR is about whether we can do better still, by reducing the number of comparisons further.

You cannot change/update elements in a `std::priority_queue`, and that is exactly what we we need to do. This is the algorithm of the critical loop

```cpp
  std::priority_queue<head, std::vector<head>, decltype(cmp)> heads(cmp);

  while (!heads.empty()) {
    const head& t = heads.top();
    sorted.write(t.value);
    std::size_t chunk_idx = t.idx;
    heads.pop();
    if (auto& chunk = chunks[chunk_idx]; chunk.current != chunk.end) {
      heads.push({*(chunk.current), chunk_idx});
      ++(chunk.current);
    }
  }
```

So, it seems very inefficient to call `queue.pop()` and then `queue.push()` both of which need to move elements through the heap. It would seem more efficient to just "change" the `.top()` (having read it and written it to output), to the new value (essentially calling `std::next` or `++` on the iterator of that chunk) and then "re-heapifying".

Let get under the hood of `std::priority_queue`. The canonical way to do this using the c++ STL heap algorithms  is:

```cpp
  // Note I am using a max-heap, but the comparator is customisable below
  std::pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comp);
  heap.pop_back();
  heap.push_back(newval);
  std::push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comp);
```

Most [heap implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Implementation) use primitives underneath called something like "bubble/sift up/down". All we actually need is the `bubble_down` implementation and call that on the changed, `top()` element.

The c++ standard does not offer primitives, but implementations are not hard and there are 2 (one iterative and one recursive) in the code below.

**Investigation Focus**

1. Relatively small heaps (3 => 100 elements, but easily adjustable in code below)
2. Operation: Update the `heap.top()` element **ONLY**
3. Optimisation criteria = number of comparisons to re-heapify

This is a very simple case. No question of "knowing where the element to be changed is in the heap" - a typical concern with this approach. So surely we can do better, right...?

The code below studies 4 implementations:

1. STL way as above  (using libstdc++-11). This is the base case. (Note that I believe libc++ is less sophisticated in this area).
2. A recursive "bubble down" algo
3. An iterative "bubble down" algo
4. A libstd++ `__adjust_heap` followed by `__push_heap` algo

I generate random heap sizes, contents and replacement value and iterate 1M times.

**Findings**

1. The STL is **Good**
2. The recursive and iterative bubble down alogs are nearly identical (expected, because the compiler, on `-O3`, "tailcall optimises" the recursion away) and, surprisingly, consistently have **more comparisons than the STL** even for this very specialised case. **So just using a heap-primitive doesn't give you any gains**.
3. We can beat the STL using...  **the STL** , by copying out the code of the unpublished functions, "cleaning them up" (of underscores etc) and using them in a specialised way to solve this limited, specialised problem. **Gains are in the order of 10-20%**. A modest, but significant gain?

Typical results:

```
method                              avg_cmp_cnt
std::heap / std::priority_queue     7.568285
bubble up recursively               8.031054
bubble up iteratively               8.047352
libstc++ __adjust_heap              6.327297
```

The code:

```cpp
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <stdexcept>

template <std::unsigned_integral T>
T log2(T x) {
  T log = 0;
  while (x >>= 1U) ++log;
  return log;
}

template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<>>
void print_heap(const std::vector<T>& heap, Comp comp = {}) {
  std::size_t levels = log2(heap.size()) + 1;
  unsigned    width  = 6 * (1U << (levels - 1U));
  std::cout << "\n\n";
  for (const auto& e: heap) std::cout << e << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::cout << fmt::format("is_heap = {:}\n\n", std::is_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comp));
  if (heap.empty()) {
    std::cout << "<empty heap>\n";
    return;
  }
  unsigned idx  = 0;
  bool     done = false;
  for (unsigned l = 0; l != levels; ++l) {
    for (unsigned e = 0; e != 1U << l; ++e) {
      std::cout << fmt::format("{:^{}}", heap[idx], width);
      ++idx;
      if (idx == heap.size()) {
        done = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    width /= 2;
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    if (done) break;
  }
}

template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<>>
void replace_top_using_stl(std::vector<T>& heap, T newval, Comp comp = {}) {

  if (heap.empty()) throw std::domain_error("can't replace_top on an empty heap");

  assert(std::is_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comp));

  std::pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comp);
  heap.pop_back();
  heap.push_back(newval);
  std::push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comp);
}

template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<>>
// NOLINTNEXTLINE recursion is tailcall eliminated by compiler
void bubble_down_recursively(std::vector<T>& heap, std::size_t i, Comp comp = {}) {
  const auto left  = 2 * i + 1;
  const auto right = 2 * i + 2;
  const auto n     = heap.size();

  using std::swap; // enable ADL

  if (left >= n) { // no children
    return;
  } else if (right >= n) { // left exists right does not.  NOLINT else after return
    if (comp(heap[i], heap[left])) {
      swap(heap[i], heap[left]);
      bubble_down_recursively(heap, left, comp);
    }
  } else { // both children exist
    // 'larger' is only well named if comp = std::less<>{}
    auto larger = comp(heap[right], heap[left]) ? left : right;
    if (comp(heap[i], heap[larger])) {
      swap(heap[i], heap[larger]);
      bubble_down_recursively(heap, larger, comp);
    }
  }
}

template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<>>
void replace_top_using_bubble_down_recursively(std::vector<T>& heap, T newval, Comp comp = {}) {

  if (heap.empty()) throw std::domain_error("can't replace_top on an empty heap");

  assert(std::is_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comp));

  heap[0] = newval;
  bubble_down_recursively(heap, 0, comp);
}

template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<>>
void bubble_down_iteratively(std::vector<T>& heap, std::size_t i, Comp comp = {}) {
  const auto n = heap.size();

  while (true) {
    const std::size_t left  = 2 * i + 1;
    const std::size_t right = 2 * i + 2;

    std::size_t largest = i;

    if ((left < n) && comp(heap[largest], heap[left])) {
      largest = left;
    }
    if ((right < n) && comp(heap[largest], heap[right])) {
      largest = right;
    }

    if (largest == i) {
      break;
    }

    using std::swap; // enable ADL
    swap(heap[i], heap[largest]);
    i = largest;
  }
}

template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<>>
void replace_top_using_bubble_down_iteratively(std::vector<T>& heap, T newval, Comp comp = {}) {

  if (heap.empty()) throw std::domain_error("can't replace_top on an empty heap");

  assert(std::is_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comp));

  heap[0] = newval;                       // stick it in anyway
  bubble_down_iteratively(heap, 0, comp); // and fix the heap
}

// borrowed from libstdc++ __push_heap
template <typename RandomAccessIterator, typename Distance, typename Tp, typename Compare>
constexpr void push_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, Distance holeIndex, Distance topIndex,
                         Tp value, Compare& comp) {
  Distance parent = (holeIndex - 1) / 2;
  while (holeIndex > topIndex && comp(*(first + parent), value)) {
    *(first + holeIndex) = *(first + parent);
    holeIndex            = parent;
    parent               = (holeIndex - 1) / 2;
  }
  *(first + holeIndex) = std::move(value);
}

// borrowed from libstdc++ __adjust_heap
template <typename RandomAccessIterator, typename Distance, typename Tp, typename Compare>
constexpr void adjust_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, Distance holeIndex, Distance len, Tp value,
                           Compare comp) {
  const Distance topIndex    = holeIndex;
  Distance       secondChild = holeIndex;
  while (secondChild < (len - 1) / 2) {
    secondChild = 2 * (secondChild + 1);
    if (comp(*(first + secondChild), *(first + (secondChild - 1)))) secondChild--;
    *(first + holeIndex) = *(first + secondChild);
    holeIndex            = secondChild;
  }
  if ((len & 1) == 0 && secondChild == (len - 2) / 2) {
    secondChild          = 2 * (secondChild + 1);
    *(first + holeIndex) = *(first + (secondChild - 1));
    holeIndex            = secondChild - 1;
  }
  push_heap(first, holeIndex, topIndex, value, comp);
}

template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<>>
void replace_top_using_adjust_heap(std::vector<T>& heap, T newval, Comp comp = {}) {

  if (heap.empty()) throw std::domain_error("can't replace_top on an empty heap");

  assert(std::is_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comp));

  heap[0] = newval;
  adjust_heap(heap.begin(), 0L, heap.end() - heap.begin(), newval, comp);
}

template <typename T>
struct cmp_counter {
  static std::size_t cmpcount; // NOLINT must be static because STL takes Comp by value
  bool               operator()(T a, T b) {
    ++cmpcount;
    return a < b; // effectively std::less<>{};
  }
  static void reset() { cmpcount = 0; }
};
template <typename T>
std::size_t cmp_counter<T>::cmpcount = 0; // NOLINT global static

int main() {

  using ValueType = int;
  
  struct method {
    using cb_t = void (*)(std::vector<ValueType>&, ValueType, cmp_counter<ValueType>);
    std::string label;
    cb_t        cb;
  };
  auto methods = std::vector<method>{
      {"std::heap / std::priority_queue", &replace_top_using_stl},
      {"bubble up recursively", &replace_top_using_bubble_down_recursively},
      {"bubble up iteratively", &replace_top_using_bubble_down_iteratively},
      {"libstc++ __adjust_heap", &replace_top_using_adjust_heap},
  };

  std::cout << fmt::format("{:35s} {:s}\n", "method", "avg_cmp_cnt");
  for (auto& method: methods) {
    auto prng              = std::mt19937_64(1); // NOLINT fixed seed for repeatability
    auto heap_element_dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(1, 100);
    auto heap_size_dist    = std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>(3, 100);

    const std::size_t number_of_trials = 1'000'000;

    std::size_t total_cmpcount = 0;
    cmp_counter<ValueType> comp;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != number_of_trials; ++i) {
      std::vector<int> h(heap_size_dist(prng));
      std::generate(h.begin(), h.end(), [&] { return ValueType(heap_element_dist(prng)); });

      std::make_heap(h.begin(), h.end(), comp);

      auto newval = ValueType(heap_element_dist(prng));
      cmp_counter<ValueType>::reset();
      method.cb(h, newval, comp);
      total_cmpcount += cmp_counter<ValueType>::cmpcount;

      if (!std::is_heap(h.begin(), h.end(), comp)) {
        std::cerr << method.label << "NOT A HEAP ANYMORE!!\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    }
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:35s} {:f}\n", method.label,
                             double(total_cmpcount) / number_of_trials);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure that the best metric is the compare count.

Comment: @MartinYork I would argue it is for my use case, because the CPU is spending > 80% in comparing 2 `std::array<std::byte, 20>`. I proved that to be the case. I am trying to "reduce the thing that the CPU is spending all its time on". And that for me is the no of comparisons, because I doubt I can improve `memcmp`. TBH, no of comparisons is also a very standard metric for sorting algorithms?  (Note that this code is using ValueType = int, for ease of debugging and printing, which is perhaps misleading. The actual application is 20 byte arrays, as explained).

Comment: @MartinYork When I switched from `std::min_element` to `std::priority_queue` and the number of comparisons more than halved, the wall clock execution time for the merge stage went from 6mins to 3mins. And it's still all at 100% CPU. All in `operator<` for the 20 byte array. Unbelievably for me, the bottleneck is NOT the disk for this stage.

Comment: Sure it is important (and a good first pass to get a good algorithm). But your original description has you reading from 20 files (rather than a generated in memory merge). I would venture that when you switch to using the 20 files your time will move to other places. I would think about the data structures you need to efficiently handling getting the next value once you have used the current top value.

Comment: @MartinYork I already have all the other code. This is not speculative optimisation. The real code with the real data with 20 x 1GB files spends 100% CPU in `operator<` of the 20 byte array during the merge stage. Right now the chunking stage takes 3 minutes and the merge stage takes 3mins (suing prority queue - the base case above). This CR is about reducing the 3mins for the merge stage. The only way that I can see is reducing the number of calls to `operator<`. If you can suggest a concrete alternative, given the above,  please do.

Comment: How does the your code compare to `sort --merge`?

Comment: @MartinYork Haven't tried, because I didn't think it could do that? Can it? More precisely the structure of the file is `struct { std::array<std::byte, 20>; int32_t; };` ie each record is 24 bytes long. There are no field separators or newlines. ie a file with 10 records would be exactly 240bytes in size. Only the 20 bytes get compared. Can I get `sort` to understand that? Reading `man sort`, it's not obvious how? I could produce a "text" version of the file, for the purpose of benchmarking? Would that even be a fair comparison? But are we getting a little "off-topic"?

Comment: @G.Sliepen That's a good spot.. Desync'd code and results. The range for `heap_element_dist` should be `(1,100)` -- not (1,1000) -- to match those result. With your permission I will fix that above. But actually... that doesn't explain such a large difference? Oh.,. BTW, I found that in some cases you need -O3 to get an accurate count of comparisons.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock The problem was the `assert(std::is_heap(..., comp))` calls that were also counting, if I add `-DNDEBUG` to the compiler options I get the same results as you.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Ahhh.. that makes sense. Yeah I have been developing this mostly in "release", so hadn't spotted that. Explains why I was getting "funny" counts when I did switch to debug mode occasionally! ;-) Actually I find the whole `assert()` macro thing quite unsatisfactory.. this is just one of many examples. But I am not aware of good alternatives. Looking forward to your answer on that!

Comment: Are your structures padded to full 4 or 8 bytes? If you use a 1-byte alignment and store data in an array, the 20-byte arrays in consecutive elements may be mis-aligned with respect to each other. Then `memcmp` can not optimize memory access with long word reads and must iterate byte by byte in the worst case. (That, however, should not matter, as hash keys should need just one byte comparison in 255/256 cases on average... provided they are quite well distributed.)

Comment: @CiaPan It's a good thought. The struct containing the hashes is struct pawned_pw { std::array<std::byte, 20> hash;
  std::int32_t              count; 
}; and `alignof` reports that is 4-byte aligned. The structs are buffered off the disk, 1000 at a time. so ~24k of data in a vector all 4-byte aligned. On this same idea though, see my self answer below https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/274768/212940  which follows a similar train of thought. The hashes are SHA1's so they are quite well distributed and the first 64-bit compare (see below), will probably discriminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Minimizing comparisons

All the algorithms you have tested need \$O(\log N)\$ comparisons. The `__adjust_heap()` method seems to save about one comparison on average. I am not sure if you can do much better than that using heaps or trees to sort the priority queue.

It might be possible to do a space vs. time tradeoff. If you could find a way to compress the keys such that the index into an array of buckets that is several times larger than the number of chunks, then inserting or removing a key from that array would on average not need any comparisons, as a bucket would most likely be empty on insertion or have 1 element on removal. Then the remaining problem is finding the first bucket with an item in it, which would have its own cost that scales with the number of buckets, but which can probably be done very cheaply. The trick is then finding a balance so maintaining this array is cheaper than maintaining a heap.

As for the code itself:

## Use `std::ranges`

You are using C++20 features, but I'm missing the use of [`std::ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges), which would simplify some of the code.

## Use `std::bit_width()` to implement `log2()`

I am a bit surprised that both GCC and Clang did not manage to optimize your naive implementation of the integer base-2 logarithm. But if you use [`std::bit_width() - 1`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width), they manage to replace the loop with a `lzcnt` instruction on x86 architectures.

## Make your code even more generic

You did make a significant effort to make your code generic by templating it on the value type of the container and on the comparison functions, however you should be able to make it work on containers other than `std::vector`. I would just copy the interface of `std::ranges::pop_heap()` and related functions.

For extra fun, you could make `cmp_counter()` a function adapter, that by default adapts `std::less` but that would allow you to have it add a counter to any comparison operator.

## Make use of `front()` and `back()`

Especially if you make your code more generic, you shouldn't assume that the containers are random accessible, and avoid code like `heap[0] = ...`. Instead you can write things like:

```
heap.front() = newval;
```

And you can replace the `pop()` and `push()` operations with a single `heap.back() = newval` inside `replace_top_using_stl()`.

## Add more `static` and `const`

I already see good use of `const`, but no `static` outside of `cmp_counter`. Consider making most functions `static`. Furthermore, you can use `const` in more cases. And in particular, `methods` can be made a `static const` array.

## Inconsistent use of `fmt::format()`

I see `fmt::format()` in a few places, but in other cases you just concatenate output using `<<`. I recommend using `fmt::format()` consistently. Even better, avoid having to write `std::cout <<` by using `fmt::print()`.

Comment: Good comments. I will think about the algorithmic nuggets. I started with more `ranges`, but there are still annoying gaps in it. I think it was `std::generate` here, and the the code slides torwards iterators. TBH, ranges i nice for me not because of `begin` and `end`, or becaue the `|` but because of `proj` support. I thought about containers other than vector, but really given the random access, nothing else will really do. good comments about `static` I don't `fmt::print` because unfortunately it won't be in `std` until c++23, so I am in the unsatisfying "in between land".

Comment: But `fmt::print()` works already in C++11, it's `std::print()` that needs to wait for C++23 ;)

Comment: I had the `for` over vector as `fmt::format("{}", v)` but then I put a different value type which implemented `operator<<`  implemented and it no longer worked... so back to `std::cout <<`. Fair comment on `front()` `back()`, this was just lazy code, I would not "commit" that. Wan't aware of `std::bit_width`, so that's good. Re being generic When I splice this into the main code (if I do, because even 20% seems like not enough to make a real difference) I would use the std::ranges type signatures with `Proj proj = std:identity`.

Comment: re `fmt::print()` well yeah.. obviously I know that. But the problem is it's much harder to `grep/sed/replace` that... I am using the c++20 parts of `fmt::format`, because I expect that in 6 months that will be in clang and gcc. It's already in MSVC. But I am not prepared to write code which requires some massive external "just to print stuff" when it's not in the standard. Come c++23 I will happily use `std::print`.

Comment: This is a good way to find "asserts with side effects": https://stackoverflow.com/a/35294344/1087626  and it finds those `cmpcount` ones in my code very easily!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that trick, very nice! As for `fmt` vs `std`, unfortunately it seems like the standard library is much further behind on the latest standards than the compilers themselves, I've also found gaps in ranges support. So even in 2023 you might still not *effectively* have `std::print`.

Comment: I am not understanding how your bucket approach can be fast because the search will be so large and cache will probably be a factor.  The 20 byte arrays are actually SHA1 hashes, so they have very random distribution. There is probably something one can do with vectorised intrinsics but that's not portable and ties it to specfic hardware. I have no idea how much my `memcmp` takes advantage of my hardware.. probably not all, because it can't.

Comment: re O(log(n))... Yes they are all that. But just because something "scales" as "log(n)" in BIgO notation doesn't mean that in actual counts it is not 2log(n) or 3log(n) or 2log(n)+5 etc... BigO notation ignores constants, right? Both Multiplicative and additive constants. And that was kind of the precisely the point of this investigation. Especially because `n` is very small here... so even an additive constant can make a 20% difference.

Comment: Correct, that notation ignores constant *factors*. But it seems the number of comparisons is actually equal to \$\log_2(N)\$ plus a small constant.

Comment: Well yes... that's because we have cherry picked here. If we used the libc++ implementation of the naive `std::pop_heap` / `std::push_heap` approach which I believe uses bubble_up and bubble down EACH internally, then we could easily get to 4 * log(n). TBH I am slightly surprised at the "STL" version above. Looking at the code, it should be at least 2*log(n) to my eyes, but I have not delved deeply. We also have to remember that the random data I used, while perhaps realistic, is not the "worst case", which is what the theory calculates.

Comment: et voila!   just did a "max" instead of average... and that is 11 for STL and 8 for the others. when heap_size is fixed at 20... but what we care about in reality is probably data dependant and in the absence of any info the random is quite good. The "max" is just that... theory.

Comment: I posted another answer below... not "on topic" of algorihmic improvement... but it works.

Comment: What is the advantage of making `methods` static? `const`, yes, fair enough. And other functions static to reduce the visibility outside this file and allow to compile ommit them altogether if they get inlined. `log2` and `print_heap` are a classic cases for `static`. But why `methods`? That's a nice "automatic storage" (ie stack) local `const` variable now... why make it more (!) complicated by making it static? As a stack/auotmatic `const` variable it's just 2x4 pointers, right?

Comment: `static` makes it a global variable instead of a stack variable, the compiler can then just compute the array at compile time (even with function pointers, the run-time linker will relocate them).

Comment: yeah, it's a noble aim, but not quite. For that to work, the `std::string` in `struct method` needs to be a `const char*` and `methods` needs to be a `std::array` or a .. cough. C-array. https://godbolt.org/z/h7ncd8f4e

Comment: did you have a view on the "crazy" intrinsics in my self answer below?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a `static const` C-array IMO. The answer below is not an answer to your original question. But if it's faster and you are no longer CPU-bound, that is great!

Comment: I agree about the C-array. I hate the initialization syntax vagaries of `std::array` for simple things like this -- double braces, have to hand count the elements and specify the length...

I agree it's not really an answer. I didn't show that code. Although it was described.  The key lesson is that  I made an assumption, which I also stated, that: I would be unlikely to be able to beat `memcmp`.. in fact, it was quite easy to thoroughly beat it. By much more than than there was further algorithmic room for improvement as it turns out....

Comment: I reworded my self answer to make clear it's not a direct answer, and to show the implicit assumption that was hiding the biggest gains.

Answer (score 3):

### Don't assume you can't beat `memcmp`

This is not directly an answer to the algorithm focused CR above, however, it does successfully challenge the implicit assumption that "we can't beat `memcmp`" - with spectacular results.

If `std::array<std::byte, 20>::operator<` comparisons are the bottleneck, then we can:

1. reduce the number of comparisons
2. make those comparisons faster

The above CR, and its accepted answer, focus on 1.

It turns out that the potential for improvements is greater in 2.

In other words, it's relatively easy to "squeeze more out of the hardware" in doing those comparisons. To go faster than `memcmp`, by using the 64-bit bus and registers rather than compare a byte at a time, or whatever your version of `memcmp` is doing.

### String Intrinsics are fast

The code below is not pretty and not entirely portable. It can probably be made portable, with some effort.

The first approach was to use the `_mm_cmpestri` [intrinsic](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_cmpestri&ig_expand=959), available with `-msse4.2`,  for the first 16 bytes and then use a `uint32_t` comparison for the last 4 bytes:

```cpp
  bool operator<(const pawned_pw& rhs) const {

    const __m128i simd_a = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(&hash));
    const __m128i simd_b = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(&rhs.hash));

    auto res = static_cast<unsigned>(_mm_cmpestri(simd_a, 16, simd_b, 16,
                                                  unsigned(_SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_EACH) |
                                                      unsigned(_SIDD_NEGATIVE_POLARITY) |
                                                      unsigned(_SIDD_UBYTE_OPS)));

    if (res != 16) {
      return hash[res] < rhs.hash[res]; // something in first 16 bytes differs
    }

    // this compiles to a load and `bswap` which should be cheap
    std::uint32_t tail     = __builtin_bswap32(*(std::uint32_t*)(&hash[16]));
    std::uint32_t rhs_tail = __builtin_bswap32(*(std::uint32_t*)(&rhs.hash[16]));
    return tail < rhs_tail;
  }
```

### Simple, 64-bit unsigned ints are even faster

Once we have figured out how to do the necessary byte order reversal on the typical little endian systems, we can just go all the way, and do the first 16 bytes using 2 x 64-bit compares as well. It turns out this is significantly faster than the more sophisticated string compare intrinsic.

```cpp
  bool operator<(const pawned_pw& rhs) const {

    // this compiles to a load and `bswap` which should be cheap
    // measured > 33% faster than hash < rhs.hash
    std::uint64_t head     = __builtin_bswap64(*(std::uint64_t*)(&hash[0]));
    std::uint64_t rhs_head = __builtin_bswap64(*(std::uint64_t*)(&rhs.hash[0]));
    if (head != rhs_head) return head < rhs_head;

    std::uint64_t mid     = __builtin_bswap64(*(std::uint64_t*)(&hash[8]));
    std::uint64_t rhs_mid = __builtin_bswap64(*(std::uint64_t*)(&rhs.hash[8]));
    if (mid != rhs_mid) return mid < rhs_mid;

    std::uint32_t tail     = __builtin_bswap32(*(std::uint32_t*)(&hash[16]));
    std::uint32_t rhs_tail = __builtin_bswap32(*(std::uint32_t*)(&rhs.hash[16]));
    return tail < rhs_tail;
  }
```

This implementation of `operator<` is ~50% (or 2x) faster than the naive `hash < rhs.hash` which calls `memcmp`.

That means the merge stage of the main application is now > 33% faster.  ie from 3mins down to ~1:50min; a very significant gain. This is still using the `std::priority_queue` so we can harvest the gains from `__adjust_heap` as well, and they will be additive.

Although not fully additiive, as we are now in the happy position of the merge stage no longer being CPU bound. CPU now at ~75-80%.

### Retain flexibility

For a slight bit of polish, we can notice that intrinsics much are nicer than embedded assembly, because they allow us to easily mix modern c++ features with low level machine instructions. Here, it turns out that we can trivially modify the above to support the c++20 `operator<=>`:

```cpp
  std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const pawned_pw& rhs) const {

    // this compiles to a load and `bswap` which should be cheap
    // measured > 33% faster than hash < rhs.hash
    std::uint64_t head     = __builtin_bswap64(*(std::uint64_t*)(&hash[0]));     // NOLINT
    std::uint64_t rhs_head = __builtin_bswap64(*(std::uint64_t*)(&rhs.hash[0])); // NOLINT
    if (head != rhs_head) return head <=> rhs_head;

    std::uint64_t mid     = __builtin_bswap64(*(std::uint64_t*)(&hash[8]));     // NOLINT
    std::uint64_t rhs_mid = __builtin_bswap64(*(std::uint64_t*)(&rhs.hash[8])); // NOLINT
    if (mid != rhs_mid) return mid <=> rhs_mid;

    std::uint32_t tail     = __builtin_bswap32(*(std::uint32_t*)(&hash[16]));     // NOLINT
    std::uint32_t rhs_tail = __builtin_bswap32(*(std::uint32_t*)(&rhs.hash[16])); // NOLINT
    return tail <=> rhs_tail;
  }
```

And, of course, we would do `operator==` the same way, except we don't need to bother with the `bswap` for an equality comparison:

```cpp
  bool operator==(const pawned_pw& rhs) const {
    std::uint64_t head     = *(std::uint64_t*)(&hash[0]);     // NOLINT
    std::uint64_t rhs_head = *(std::uint64_t*)(&rhs.hash[0]); // NOLINT
    if (head != rhs_head) return false;

    std::uint64_t mid     = *(std::uint64_t*)(&hash[8]);     // NOLINT
    std::uint64_t rhs_mid = *(std::uint64_t*)(&rhs.hash[8]); // NOLINT
    if (mid != rhs_mid) return false;

    std::uint32_t tail     = *(std::uint32_t*)(&hash[16]);     // NOLINT
    std::uint32_t rhs_tail = *(std::uint32_t*)(&rhs.hash[16]); // NOLINT
    return tail == rhs_tail;
  }
```

Comment: Using `auto` makes it nicer.

Answer (score 1):

**Reducing the number of comparisons** *in heap operation*
About half of the entries introduced to the heap end up being leaves.
One suggestion was to [be realistic about this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Bottom-up_heapsort) and
determine the path to the leaves before even looking at the new key.

```
/** re-heapify 0-based heap when heap[root] may break ordering below
 *    (not have priority over all its children). 
 * switched shall return true if its right operand has priority over its left. */
// index runs towards bottom of heap and bounces up to root, again
void 
bounce_iteratively(std::vector<T>& heap, std::size_t root, Comp switched = {}) {
    const auto
        n = heap.size(),
        first_leaf = n / 2,
        last_parent_of_two = (n-3) / 2;
    if (first_leaf <= root)
        return;
    std::size_t i = root;
    while (i <= last_parent_of_two) { // a first comparison per level
        const std::size_t
            left  = 2 * i + 1,
            right = left + 1;
        i = switched(heap[right], heap[left])) ? left : right;
    }
    if (i < first_leaf))// parent of one ...
        i = 2 * i + 1;  // repeated expression  // left;
  // all below can be replaced by call to (std::?)push_heap()??
    T addition = heap[root];
    using std::swap; // enable ADL
    for ( ; root < i ; i = (i-1)/2)
        if (switched(addition, heap[i])) {  // the second comparison per level
            swap(addition, heap[i]);
            break;
        }
    for ( ; root <= i ; i = (i-1)/2)
        swap(addition, heap[i]);  // no more comparisons
}
```

(This is actually close to what I'd expect `replace_top_using_stl()`'s  `pop_heap;pop_back;push_back;push_heap` to do, esp. re. sequence of comparisons.)

---

- The obvious&ultimate way to reduce comparisons in a sort is to use a non-comparison sort.
  Even just partitioning the key space initially into 20 parts (to keep the number thereof) or 32 (to account for uneven distribution or perceived difficulty in computing part#), you could just keep writing/concatenate instead of merging.
- With *n* = 20, I'd evaluate *binary search & insertion in an ordered array*.
- You state `alignof` to report *4-byte aligned*.
  While I don't see how to ruin 8-byte alignment with even numbers (`[buffered] 1000 at a time`) of 24(?)-byte `struct pawned_pw`, using `alignas(8)` was explicit. (24K seems a bit low for late mechanical mass storage devices - and for system calls.)

Comment: I'm increasingly out of my depth with C++, esp. *modern C++*.

Comment: Would replacing `heap.pop_back();
  heap.push_back(newval);` with `heap.back() = newval;` make any difference?